# Error with String to DateTime conversion in PowerShell (it used to work before)

Tags: powershell, datetime, datetime-format

A script is parsing values from a `*.csv` file. 
One of the values is a timestamp in the format `7/21/2018 7:07 AM UTC`

This line used to work before:

```
$DR.Item($property.Name) = (
 [System.DateTime](Get-Date($property.value -replace " UTC", ""))
).TolocalTime() -f "MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

It is not working anymore. I get the following error:

`Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "7/21/2018 7:07 AM" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid
DateTime."`

Comment: Try this: ([System.DateTime](Get-Date($($property.value) -replace " UTC", ""))).Tolocaltime() -f "MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Comment: @uSlackr: Wrapping `$property.value` in `$(...)` not only makes no difference here, it adds unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command failing suggests that the *current culture* (`[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture`) at the time of execution is something *other* than `en-US` (US-English), in which case `Get-Date` won't recognize a date/time string such as `"7/21/2018 7:07 AM`<sup>[1]</sup>.

The solution is to **use a `[datetime]` cast *directly*, without involving `Get-Date`**, because a `[datetime]`*cast* *always uses the [invariant culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture)*, which is *like* the `en-US` culture with respect to date/time formats:

```
$DR.Item($property.Name) = ([datetime] ($property.value -replace ' UTC$')) -f "MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

**Caveat**: Your call to `.ToLocalTime()` is not needed for output formatting, as the `[datetime]` instance you receive will behave as if it were in local time by default, even though it technically is time-zone-agnostic, as reflected in its `.Kind` property containing `Unspecified`. That is, your output will reflect the *UTC* date and time, without indicating so.
If you truly want to translate the input UTC timestamp into the equivalent local time, more work is needed:

```
$dtUtc = [datetime]::SpecifyKind(($property.value -replace ' UTC$'), 'Utc')
$DR.Item($property.Name) = $dtUtc.ToLocalTime() -f "MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell generally uses the *invariant culture* when it comes to from-string and to-string type conversions, but, curiously, doesn't do so when passing strings as *arguments* to *compiled cmdlets*, as opposed to [advanced] *functions* (written in PowerShell).
This is a [known problem](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6989), but it may not get fixed for reasons of backward compatibility.</sup>